# What version of Drools are Java 7 and Hibernate 3.0 compatible with?

Tags: java, hibernate, version, drools

I'm trying to integrate Drools into a Java 7 + Hibernate 3.0 project. Are Drools packages (most importantly JBPM) version 6.0 compatible with my current setup? My google-fu has failed me.

Thanks!

Comment: I am in a similar situation, do you have any recomendations?

Comment: Geez, I haven't thought about it in most of a year. I can't say I remember.

Answer (score 0):

As of Drools 6.0, we moved from Hibernate 3.5 to Hibernate 4.2. Drools 6.0 is Java 6.0 compatible.

I looked up the Jira's, and it looks like persistence was added in 5.0 (See [JBRULES-1761](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-1761)). 5.0 is thus probably your best chance -- but I suspect that 5.0 is probably Hibernate 3.3.x compatible (and not Hibernate 3.0.x compatible).

I  highly recommend moving from Hibernate 3.0 to Hibernate 4.2.x or higher: for one, Hibernate 3.0 is based on JPA 1, which is an old standard. Most companies/organizations moved to JPA 2 when moving to Java 6+.